# Automatting Radar Chart Generation in Google Doc using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to insert a radar chart in **Google Docs** using **Google Apps Script**. The chart is in **Google Sheets** but it turned out to be very ugly in Google Docs.

I found a post on SO that suggested to create the chart using Apps Script directly but that does not really worked for me either.

If any one can point to further `setOptions()` that I can use to achieve the desired result that would be great.

**This is what I am trying to achieve in google docs:**
[image: Expected Radar Chart]

**This is my code:**

```
function createChart() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var chart = sheet.newChart();

chart
.addRange(sheet.getRange("K2:K7"))
.addRange(sheet.getRange("G2:G7"))
.addRange(sheet.getRange("I2:J7"))
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.RADAR)
.setNumHeaders(1)
.setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
.setOption("colors",["#e0296c", "#0000ff", "#ff9900"])
.setOption('width', 700)
.setOption('height', 600)
.setOption('legend', {position: 'bottom', textStyle: {fontSize: 12}})
.setPosition(1,1,0,0)
.setOption('vAxis.gridlines.count', 4)
.setOption('series', {  0: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 5},
                        1: { lineDashStyle: [4, 4] },
                        2: { lineDashStyle: [4, 4] }
                        })
.setOption('hAxis.format',{format: 'percent'})

chart = chart.build();

sheet.insertChart(chart);

var doc = DocumentApp.openById("DOC_ID");
var body = doc.getBody();

var chartBlob = chart.getAs('image/png').copyBlob();
body.appendImage(chartBlob);

}
```

**This is what I have achieved till now:**

in GSHEETS
[image]

in GDOCS
[image]

Comment: Closed as there is accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62038597/

Comment: The answer you shared is for Google Slides and NOT for google docs as this question asks for.

Comment: You didn't read the answer properly. Tanaike uses a workaround using slides , but **IT IS FOR GOOGLE DOCS** See the last script in the question: That should be the fully working script.

Comment: I did read the answer PROPERLY. But it seems I didnot read the edit part of the question. I apologize. Hope it is helpful for someone in future.

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the answer,  feel free to add a answer there with full script/ better explanations. If you feel your question is somehow different, [edit] your question to show how the answer there is not applicable and your question will be put on reopen queue.

Comment: Looks good. Closing it will help redirect people to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Google Docs feature link a chart from Google Sheets. The detailed steps are on the official G Suite Document Editors documentation, but the core step is this:

> Click **Insert** and then **Chart** and then **From Sheets**.

The above because resulting image of converting a chart to PNG, as you already found, doesn't look the same. By the other hand, the Spreadsheet Service include [Class Embedded Chart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart) but the Document Service don't.

You could try to use [EmdeddedObject](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/EmbeddedObject) from the Docs API by using the new [Documents Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs).

Ref

[Link a chart, table, or slides to Google Docs or Slides](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Thank you Ruben for your response. BUT I am trying to automate generating charts in Google Docs. I know how to link the chart from sheets and then update with new data. Problem is no function lets you update chart using GAS. And this led me to creating chart from scratch so that I can automate it.

Comment: I am looking for a Google Apps Script solution for the problem.