# Exporting Google Sheet Chart to Google Doc Issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-docs

I am working on Exporting a chart from Google Sheet to Google doc. But somehow that original google sheet chart does not Export to Google doc. It's color and size is different and some of the graphs' data is also missing in google docs. Also I want to resize the exported chart in Google doc. Following is the Script:

```
    function open() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1x41183-Fhn3BRPi3CFzEhB9vStGqXCgt00Z7fuZiq3s');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  

  var search = body.findText("Graph_Here");
  
  if(search!= null)
  {
  var element = search.getElement();
  var parent = element.getParent();
  var paragraph = parent.asParagraph();
    
  var chart = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts()[0]; //Get First Chart of Google Sheet

  paragraph.insertInlineImage(1, chart).getAs("image/png");  // Place the Chart into the Google Doc 
  paragraph.getChild(2).removeFromParent();                 // Remove the previous chart 
    
  }
  
  else 
  {
     Logger.log("No place Holder");
  }
}
```

Any Suggestions would be Appreciated.

Comment: I think that the answer of this thread might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62038597

Comment: Yes, I found solution there. Thank you.