# Secondary axis not showing in embedded chart images Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some code that sends emails containing images of graphs from a spreadsheet, however one of the graphs which has a secondary axis is only sending the graph with the left axis and doesn't include the right axis. I've seen some suggestion that this is a bug but there may be a workaround, can any advise? Thanks a lot. Here is my code (chart [4] is the chart with a left and right axis):

```
  var sheetSummary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
  var chartIndex = [4,0,1,2,3];
  var charts = sheetSummary.getCharts();
  var emailImages = {};
  var emailChart = "";
  chartIndex.forEach(i => {
    emailChart += "<p align='left'><img src='cid:chart" + i + "'>";
    emailImages["chart" + i] = charts[i].getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob" + i);
  });
```

Comment: By guessing your situation, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I thought that the method of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038977) might be useful. In this thread, when the blob is retrieved from a chart on Spreadsheet, the blob is the broken chart. In order to avoid this issue, I proposed to use Google Slides.

But, when I saw your script, I thought that including this method to your script might be a bit complexity. So, in this answer, I proposed a modified script of your script using above method.

#### Modified script:

```
var sheetSummary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
var chartIndex = [4,0,1,2,3];
var charts = sheetSummary.getCharts();
var emailImages = {};
var emailChart = "";

// I modified below script.
// 1. Create Google Slides as a temporal.
var slides = SlidesApp.create("temp");
var slide = slides.getSlides()[0];
chartIndex.forEach(i => {
  emailChart += "<p align='left'><img src='cid:chart" + i + "'>";
  
  // 2. Put the chart to Google Slides.
  var image = slide.insertSheetsChartAsImage(charts[i]);

  // 3. Retrieve the blob of the chart from Google Slides.
  emailImages["chart" + i] = image.getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob" + i);

  // 4. Remove the chart from Google Slides.
  image.remove();
});

// 5. Remove the Google Slides.
DriveApp.getFileById(slides.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

#### References:

- [create(name) of Class SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#createname)
- [insertSheetsChartAsImage(sourceChart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertsheetschartasimagesourcechart)
- Related thread.

  - [Get as Image generates wrong image - Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62038597)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike that still hasn't resolved the issue unfortunately, in fact it seems to be sending old versions of the same graph which is bizarre.

Comment: @George Bates Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `it seems to be sending old versions of the same graph which is bizarre.`. Because when I tested this modified script, no issue occurred. I apologize for this situation. But, I would like to confirm your situation. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? Or, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: @George Bates I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `it seems to be sending old versions of the same graph which is bizarre.`. When I tested above script using a sheet with 5 charts, 5 charts can be confirmed at the email. I deeply apologize for this situation. So, in this case, I think that it is required to know the method for replicating your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.