# How to preserve custom positive- and negative baseline colors in a Google Sheets scorecard chart when saving to file via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Problem**

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a scorecard chart with custom colors for positive and negative baseline values. When I export this chart programmatically via Google Apps Script, only the default colors are used.

[image: Scorecard chart with red as positive baseline color in Google Sheets]

**Expected Result**

I expect the positive baseline value to be red in the exported chart PNG file.

**Actual Result**

The positive baseline value is green (the default color).

[image: Exported scorecard PNG file with green positive baseline color]

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Create a new Google Sheets spreadsheet, with the following data in it:

| Value | Baseline |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 50 |

2. Highlight the four cells with data in them and, in the top menu, click **Insert** > **Chart**.
3. In the **Chart editor** panel, on the **Setup** tab, select **Scorecard chart** from the **Chart type** dropdown list.
4. In the **Chart editor** panel, on the **Customize** tab, in the **Baseline Value** section, change the **Positive color** to red and the **Negative color** to green.
5. In the **Chart editor** panel, on the **Customize** tab, in the **Chart & axis titles** section, set the chart title text to "Scorecard with red baseline color".
6. In the top menu, click **Extensions** > **Apps Script**.
7. Replace the contents of the Code.gs file with the following:

```js
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Charts')
    .addItem('Export to Drive', 'exportCharts')
    .addToUi();
}

function exportCharts() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();

  charts.forEach((chart) => {
    const image = chart.getAs('image/png');
    const title = chart.getOptions().get('title');
    DriveApp.createFile(image.setName(`${title}.png`));
  });
}
```

8. In the left side menu, where it says **Services**, click the **+** symbol and add **Drive** as a service.
9. Save the script by clicking the disk icon, then return to the Google Sheet and refresh the page.
10. A few seconds after the sheet loads, you will see a new item in the top menu; click **Charts** > **Export to Drive**. (You will be prompted to give the script permission to access your Google Drive.)
11. In Google Drive, search for a file with the name "Scorecard with red baseline color.png" and open it to confirm that the baseline color is green, not red.

Comment: I got the same behavior, I even tried with chart.getBlob() and got the same results, it is weird that the same doesn't happen if I manually save the chart as .png using the web UI. I'd highly recommend you to submit a new entry in the [Issue tracker for Google Apps Script](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) to report this issue.

Comment: When I tested your flow, I confirmed that the font color of `50` of the exported image using your script is the red color I set. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. But, in your situation, is this thread related to your current issue? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62038597/7108653) In your situation, when Google Slides is used, will your issue be resolved?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, that workaround in the other SO issue you referenced did the trick. It's a bit of a hacky workaround, but I'm strangely comfortable with it. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. I think so. Unfortunately, it seems that this method is a workaround. But, I believe that this issue will be resolved in the future update. By the way, in the current stage, I'm glad your issue was resolved by the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems to be a bug, but a comment from @Tanaike pointed me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62038597/7108653) and, based on that, I was able to use this as a workaround:

```js
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Charts')
    .addItem('Export to Drive', 'exportCharts')
    .addToUi();
}

function exportCharts() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();

  charts.forEach((chart) => {
    const image = preserveChartColors(chart);
    const title = chart.getOptions().get('title');
    DriveApp.createFile(image.setName(`${title}.png`));
  });
}

function preserveChartColors(chart) {
  const slides = SlidesApp.create("temp");
  const image = slides.getSlides()[0].insertSheetsChartAsImage(chart).getAs("image/png");
  DriveApp.getFileById(slides.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  return image;
}
```

That last function, `preserveChartColors`, creates a temporary Google Slides document and inserts the chart as an image there, extracts it as a PNG image, then deletes the temporary Slides document.